# header of gridview

Tags: c#

I have a desktop application which displays the data in Datagridview but when I click on header of Datagridview auto selection of First cell in Datagridview occurs. 
How to remove auto selection of cell in gridview?

```
  private void GV_investigate_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (GV_investigate.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            int oid = int.Parse(GV_investigate.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        }
    }

   private void GV_investigate_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        GV_investigate.ClearSelection();
    }
```

Comment: can you plz tell us, what do you want. do you want to get the selected cell value in oid??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datagridview` has an event called `ColumnHeaderMouseClick` add this event to your project then when the user clicks on Column header the event calls it's function in the function we just clear the selection :

adding event to project :

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.ColumnHeaderMouseClick += dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick;
    }
```

event Handler :

```
    private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    }
```

Comment: thankyou so much this event work in my project...& problem solved

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the selected cell values in oid then you should do something like this. in cell click event if you don't use try, catch in your coding you sometimes get error

```
private void GV_investigate_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int oid = int.Parse(GV_investigate.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());                
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

dataGridView.CurrentCell = null;